# Multiple $observe in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im trying to create a directive that only accepts numbers or decimal numbers depending of the attribute i insert in my input, the problem im having is with the decimal places declaration.

Example:
If a user whats to only this input accepts int numbers, it would be like

```
<input only-number type-num="int">
```

Case the user wants only decimal places the input would be like

```
<input only-number type-num="decimal" maxDecimalPoints="2">
```

but now i have to $observe typeNum and MaxDecimalPoints, can i nest $observe inside each other? How can i accomplishe?

Here is my directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('onlyNumber', function(){
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                if(!ngModelCtrl) {
                    return;
                }

                // Only Int Numbers
                attrs.$observe('typeNum', function(value){

                    if(value == "int"){
                        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                            if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                                var val = '';
                            }
                            var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9]+/g, '');
                            if (val !== clean) {
                                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                                ngModelCtrl.$render();
                            }
                            return parseInt(clean);
                        });
                    }

                });

                // Only Decimal
                attrs.$observe('typeNum', function(value){

                    if(value == "decimal"){

                        // Now Check limit of decimal places

                    }

                });


                element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                    if(event.keyCode === 32) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: lot of extra work when you could just use `ng-pattern` and pass pattern in as variable

Comment: but the idea is not to show error in the validation, is not letting the user be able to insert more charecters, that why i didnt use ng-pattern and also because to be able to implement more behaviours

Comment: note that `maxDecimalPoints` attribute needs to be `max-decimal-points`

Comment: @charlietfl yes i not, i forgot to edited him right

Comment: Do you really need to observe these? Seems you are hard coding values. If hard code no need to observe, just use the attribute values

Comment: Yes your right i didnt notice, i thought that i got undefined, but i just added console.log(attrs.typeNum); and i got the value, thanks anyway..:S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parser;

attrs.$observe('typeNum', function (typeNum) {
  if (parser) {
    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.splice(ngModelCtrl.$parsers.indexOf(parser), 1);
  }

  switch (typeNum) {
    case 'int':
      parser = intParser;
      break;

    case 'decimal':
      parser = decimalParser;
      break;

    default:
      return;
  }

  ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(parser);
});

// define intParser and decimalParser here
```

By the way, always add a radix argument to `parseInt` or [you’re in for big trouble](https://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix): `parseInt(clean, 10)`

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, when you say define is defining a function to decimalParser?

Comment: Yes, use `function intParser (val) { /* ... */ }` to define them instead of adding them like you did in the `$parsers` queue

Comment: ok, and thanks about parseInt, i had no idea about it, in my case i change from parseInt to Number() function, since my idea is to convert the value to a number and also the user isnt able to insert dots or commas

Comment: The parseInt radix article is from 2013 where it belongs. Not saying that you shouldn't use it - it's a small change for better browser support - but the *big trouble* is only a thing if you support IE8

Comment: Nope: `parseInt(076)` returns 62 since it's parsed as octal.